# Ошибка в коде PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php
require("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

}
else
{
<form action="register.php" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="rpassword"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Sign Out" name="submit"><br>
</form>     
}
?>
```

Пишет, что со 10 до 16 строки есть ошибки, причем в каждой строке. Когда компилирую, пишет что Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' в строке 2. Ломаю голову, но не могу найти, что это я пропустил? Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кавычки вы пропустили, echo, и закрывающий php-тег у вас неправильный

```
<?php
echo "<form action='register.php' method='POST'>
First Name: <input type='text' name='fname'><br>
Last Name: <input type='text' name='lname'><br>
Username: <input type='text' name='username'><br>
E-mail: <input type='text' name='email'><br>
Password: <input type='password' name='password'><br>
Confirm Password: <input type='password' name='rpassword'><br>
<input type='submit' value='Sign Out' name='submit'><br>
</form>"
?>
```

**upd**

```
<?php
require("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

}
else
{
echo '<form action="register.php" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="rpassword"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Sign Out" name="submit"><br>
</form>';     
}
?>
```

Comment: Не влом было все переписывать на одинарные кавычки? XDD)

Comment: автозамена рулит, чувак XD

Comment: а почему echo нужен? Да и при этом он выдал ошибку 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' on line 2

Comment: в ответе апдейт кода

Comment: получилось @Heidel. А теперь можешь объяснять почему это было?

Comment: вставки html-кода берутся в кавычки, была пропущена ; в конце кода в else

Answer (score 2):

Это в голове ошибка а не в коде! Если угодно то

```
<?php
    echo <<<EOT
    <form action="register.php" method="POST">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
        Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
        Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="rpassword"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Out" name="submit"><br>
    </form>
EOT;
?>
```

или

```
<?php
    echo '
    <form action="register.php" method="POST">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
        Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
        Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="rpassword"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Out" name="submit"><br>
    </form>';
?>
```

Покурить мануал можно [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php)

На будущее, закрывать сценарий php нужно так **`?>`** а не так **`<?`**

Comment: да знаю я как закрывать, это чисто механически случилось. Написал твой первый вариант, опять ошибка: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting T_VARIABLE or T_END_HEREDOC or T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES or T_CURLY_OPEN in Z:\home\localhost\www\php\register.php on line 24 на закрывающий тэг php - ?>

Comment: я уже даже знаю как ты вставил мой пример в свой код!

-------------------------------------

вот так

    else
    {
    <?php
    //...
    ?>
    }

Иди учи синтаксис!

Comment: откуда знаешь что так?! НЕТ не так вставлял!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
```

первую строку убери. и последнюю

```
<?
```

Ты когда за php сел синтаксис учил?

**ps 126 вопросов и 18% принятых. Это товарищи пипец.**

Comment: я его как заметил поправил. Не суди сразу так жестко. Эта механическая ошибка была

Comment: я написал, вообще убери <?php ?> из своего кода.

Comment: вот выложил весь код. Да и зачем убрать? Вы хоть объясните свой ответ

Comment: ну вот и нужно было весь сразу выкладывать а не кусками.